# Load resources in angular with oclazyload and webpack

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, webpack-2, oclazyload

I have a modular app who have multiple vendor plugins and I need to load only necessary in every view.

This is my routes:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.empresas').config(config);

    function config($stateProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.empresas', {
                url: '/empresas?Filter',
                views: {
                    'main@': {
                        template: require('./empresas/empresas.html'),
                        controller: "AppController as App"
                    }
                },
                Params: {
                    title: 'Empresas',
                    bodyClass: '',
                    requiredLogin: true
                }
            })
            .state('app.empresas.view', {
                url: '/empresas/:ItemId',
                views: {
                    'main@': {
                        template: require('./empresas.view/empresas.view.html'),
                        controller: "AppController as App"
                    }
                },
                Params: {
                    title: 'Empresa',
                    bodyClass: '',
                    requiredLogin: true
                }
            })
    }
})();
```

I know how to include oclazyload resources without webpack, but now I need to include specific resources for every view. ¿How can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this snippet:

This is a sample of a state

```
.state('app.empresas.view', {
    url: '/empresas/:ItemId',
    views: {
        'main@': {
            templateUrl: '/app/main/apps/empresas/empresas.view/empresas.view.html',
            controller: "AppController as App"
        }
    },
    Params: {
        title: 'Empresa',
        bodyClass: '',
        requiredLogin: true
    },
    resolve: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var mod = importAll(require.context('./empresas.view/', true, /\.*$/));
        $ocLazyLoad.load({
            name: 'app.empresas.view'
        });
        deferred.resolve(mod);

        return deferred.promise;
    }]
})
```

I use this function with require to load entire folder with oclazyload and compile with webpack in a bundle separate file:

```
function importAll (r) {r.keys().forEach(r);}
```

I can load css, html, js files in one view without require files one by one